# How do you expand a uicollectionviewcell based on the size of the textview in real time using Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

So what I have is a collection view with a uitextview in each cell. The cells start off with a preset size (for example: a size of 60) and as you type in the textview, the textview grows and the cell grows with it in real time.

How would I go about it? I saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jb29c22xu8
however, he doesn't use a uicollectionviewcell. Is there a method to use where the cell doesn't have a fixed width and grows with the contents inside?

Comment: are you trying to implement collection view as chat?

Comment: I should clarify. I'm using a collection view as a list. Something similar to the native reminders app on iPhone.

Comment: okay. now if you have only text than you can do it with `text.sizetofit()` otherwise you need to calculate cell height in `sizeForItemAt`method.

Comment: will that resize it in real time? I tried referencing the uitextview inside the cell in the sizeForItemAt function, but it seems way too complicated. And it doesn't adjust real time either

Comment: for real time update you need to customflowlayout delegate it might helps you alot. because i never do it with textview but i tried it with diffrent size of images.